# pg_restore complains about integrity errors on a dump. Is that even possible?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have dumped an OpenERP DB like this:

```
pg_dump -Fc -xO -f o7db.dump o7db
```

The source machine has:

```
$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
```

The I `scp` the dump to a target machine (an OpenVZ container), where pg_restore is:

```
$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
```

I run pg_restore like this:

```
pg_restore -d o7db -xO -j3 o7db.dump
```

The only difference I can see is that postgres user is not the same in both
machines (but that is supposed to be dealt by `-O`).  pg_restore complains
about:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 8561; 0 1161831 TABLE DATA account_move_line manu
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "account_move_line": ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(64)
CONTEXT:  COPY account_move_line, line 172, column name: "<MASKED DATA HERE....>"
```

This error is issued several times for several tables.  After that, many so
errors about missing tuples follow:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 6784; 2606 1182924 FK CONSTRAINT account_account_currency_id_fkey manu
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  insert or update on table "account_account" violates foreign key constraint "account_account_currency_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (currency_id)=(1) is not present in table "res_currency".
     Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY account_account
     ADD CONSTRAINT account_account_currency_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (currency_id) REFERENCES re..
```

I don't see how this is possible, since the source DB seems to be Ok.

The restored DB has many empty tables (each that failed cause too long
values):

```
 $ psql -d o7db -Ac "select * from account_move_line"  | tail -1
 (0 rows)
```

Furthermore, I do the pg_restore on the same source machine:

```
pg_restore -d o7db_restore -xO -j3 o7db.dump
```

Everything works as expected.  Not a single warning.

What should I do? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What PostgreSQL version was the dump created from ? The server version (`SELECT version()`), not client version, and what's the destination server version? Also, is the text encoding the same on both - it shouldn't matter, but let's check. `SHOW server_encoding;` on both.

Comment: Also, please check the actual data value on line 172 of that input block, where the error occurs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Moving PostgreSQL database fails on non-ascii characters with 'value too long'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842564/moving-postgresql-database-fails-on-non-ascii-characters-with-value-too-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually given in [Moving PostgreSQL database fails on non-ascii characters with 'value too long'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842564/moving-postgresql-database-fails-on-non-ascii-characters-with-value-too-long)

It seems the target server creates DB with a different encoding, so creating the DB with UTF8 before restoring solves the problem.

Credit goes to @habe (https://stackoverflow.com/users/216458/habe)

So, I have voted my question to be closed.